# Mysql Store procedure stops iteration after some rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Below procedure code running with out error . Line  **select FOUND_ROWS()** returning n no. rows but cursor **curs** did not loop all rows

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `middleLocationAutoUpdatePorc`()
    BEGIN
    declare vname varchar(45);
    declare vmobile varchar(20);
    declare vsapid varchar(6);
    declare vuser varchar(45);
    declare vday date;
    declare vmintime time;
    declare vmaxtime time;
    declare vminLocation mediumtext;
    declare vmaxLocation mediumtext;
    declare vmiddlelocation mediumtext;
    declare vdistance int(11);
    declare vdrdid int(11);
    declare vn_no_details int(11);
    declare uatt            varchar(45) default 'X';
    declare adatta          varchar(45) default 'X';
    declare b_not_found     BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    declare curs CURSOR FOR
            SELECT user ,day, mintime,maxtime_mobile,minLocation,maxLocation,distance,n_no_details,drdid FROM mydb.statusreport where day >= '2017-06-26';

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b_not_found = true;

      OPEN curs;
       loop1: LOOP
            FETCH curs INTO vuser,vday,vmintime,vmaxtime,vminLocation,vmaxLocation,vdistance,vn_no_details,vdrdid;
            IF b_not_found THEN
                LEAVE loop1;
            END IF;
    -- select FOUND_ROWS(); 
        case substring_index(vuser,"-",-1)
        when 'RSM' then 

         select username,Name,mobile into vsapid,vname,vmobile from mydb.supervisor where idSu=CONVERT(substring_index(vuser,"-",1),UNSIGNED INTEGER);
        when 'ASM' then 
          select userName,name,mobile  into vsapid,vname,vmobile from mydb.executive where exeid=CONVERT(substring_index(vuser,"-",1),UNSIGNED INTEGER);
        when 'F' then 
          select sapId,name,phone into vsapid,vname,vmobile from mydb.user where idUser=CONVERT(substring_index(vuser,"-",1),UNSIGNED INTEGER);
        end case;

        select userGiven , adminGiven into uatt ,adatta from userdaystatus st  where st.date =vday and st.idUser=CONVERT(substring_index(vuser,"-",1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) and st.userType=substring_index(vuser,"-",-1);
       set vmiddlelocation=( select location from mydb.dailyReportDetails as dtb where dtb.idDailyReport=vdrdid and dtb.counter>=(abs(vn_no_details/2) ) order by dtb.idDailyReportDetails asc limit 1);


        call mydb.addOMiddleLocation(day(vday), month(vday),
                                            year(vday),vuser, vname,
                                            vsapid, vmobile, vmintime,
                                            vmaxtime, SUBTIME(vmaxtime,vmintime), 
                                            vminLocation,
                                            vmiddlelocation,
                                            vmaxLocation,Round(vdistance/1000,2), 
                                            uatt, adatta);

              END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs;
    END
```

The Procedure call mydb.addOMiddleLocation() just inserting Row on another table.There does not have any data type validation .
So what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happen for log wait time for a particular Query line

```
set vmiddlelocation=( select location from mydb.dailyReportDetails as dtb where dtb.idDailyReport=vdrdid and dtb.counter>=(abs(vn_no_details/2) ) order by dtb.idDailyReportDetails asc limit 1);
```